# Can I connect socket before using sendmsg()?

Tags: sockets

I'm trying to pass fd between process and I found the sample code like [portlisten](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2002-January/000292.html). In the sample, a `recvmsg()` can take a bound socket as parameter (and leave msghdr.msg_name as NULL) but the `sendmsg()` cannot - it must take a `sockaddr*` in the msghdr.msg_name.

I tried to modify the program by connecting first but failed, and found the comment as `/* doesn't do anything at the moment` but I don't understand why.

Is this a limitation of sendmsg() that it cannot take an already connected socket as parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the source code of libancillary.  I can't post a link because I'm a new user, but you'll find it on Google.

Answer (score 1):

from the sendmsg man page:

> The sendmsg() function shall send a message through a connection-mode or connectionless-mode socket. If the socket is connectionless-mode, the message shall be sent to the address specified by msghdr. If the socket is connection-mode, the destination address in msghdr shall be ignored.

So that means that if you use a TCP connection the *destination address in msghdr is ignored*.

Comment: So what about UNIX domain sockets? Can I use them in connected mode?